# How to train separate models per column values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

How do you run a train different regression models based on widowing a certain column in 
a Spark Data Frame?

Let's say I have 2 products with features and labels asscoiated with those products in a single Spark DF.
The ids of the product are present in a seprate column.
I'd like to run a regression for each of the products.

So far for relaviely simple analyses, I have been using

```
w = Window().partitionBy("id")
F.sum(column).over(w)
```

E.g. Data

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(
        [("a", 1.0, 2.0, 3.0), ("a", 4.0, 1.0, 5.0), ("b", 2.0, 1.0, 0.0), ("b", 4.0, 0.0, 1.0)],
        ["id", "y", "x1", "x2"])
```

I'd like to run a separate model for id "a" and "b".

Comment: Why don't you split the DataFrame based on a condition using `filter` and use the two DataFrames separately?

Comment: Hi yes, that's one possible solution. But since I have 70,000 ids, I don't want to run a for loop for each id. is there a way to do a groupby then collect, or something like that?

Comment: You could `groupBy`, `collect_list` or `collect_set` and do a training per collections, but it's not available out of the box and would require writing a user-defined aggregate function (UDAF).

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupBy`, `collect_list` or `collect_set` and do a model training per collection, but it's not available out of the box in Spark MLlib and would require a custom development, i.e. writing a user-defined aggregate function (UDAF).

I'd recommend splitting a DataFrame based on a condition using `filter` and use the two or more DataFrames separately.

Comment: Is it possible to write a UDAF that returns a trained model? It seems like maybe not since `UserDefinedType` is now package private

Comment: No idea. I recommend asking a separate question on SO to reach out to the wider Spark MLlib community.